# Python Websockets with logging. "..." in the debug message. Message length limit

Tags: python, logging, websocket, limit

Websockets somehow limits the amount of output content in logging. At the moment I have calculated that the number of characters is limited to 70 characters. Is it possible to increase the threshold?

I need to see the full message. But instead i get '...' in output:

[image]

Code example:

*Server.py*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import asyncio

from websockets.server import serve

logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s %(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG)

async def echo(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

async def main():
    async with serve(echo, "127.0.0.1", 9954):
        await asyncio.Future()

asyncio.run(main())
```

*Client.py*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
import json

from websockets.sync.client import connect

logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s %(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG)

with connect("ws://127.0.0.1:9954") as websocket:
        websocket.send(json.dumps({"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA@": "@BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"}))
        message = websocket.recv()
        print(f"Received: {message}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found solution.

You can just comment

```py
if len(data) > 75:
    data = data[:48] + "..." + data[-24:]
```

in `__str__` method of the `Frame` class in *websockets/frames.py*